# Jade - double-nested .jade templates do not fetch public folder assets. Any Ideas?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, pug

I'm making a forum system at the moment and I have a layout.jade, posts.jade and single.jade(for a single post display) that extend the posts.jade, which itself extends the layout.jade.

The single.jade template for a single detailed post, does not fetch my css files from the public folder, even though I have specified it to be used in the server config.

Structure:

- /config
- /public
- -/css
- -/style.css
- /routes
- -/main.js (contains the callbacks for the main page requests)
- -/posts.js (contains the callbacks for the post requests)
- /views
- -/layout.jade
- -/posts.jade
- -/all.jade (extends posts.jade, which extends layout.jade)
- -/single.jade (extends posts.jade, which extends layout.jade)

### server.js

Here is the code:

server.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Routes
var main = require('./routes/main'),
    posts = require('./routes/posts'),
    postsRouter = express.Router();

app.use('/posts', postsRouter);

app.get('/', main.index);

postsRouter.get('/', posts.all);
postsRouter.get('/details/:id', posts.details);
postsRouter.post('/create/:uid', posts.create);
postsRouter.post('/destroy/:id', posts.remove);
postsRouter.post('/edit/:id', posts.edit);
```

posts.jade

```
extends ./layout.jade

block title
    title All posts

block content
    .row
        section#forum-posts.col-md-9
            .col-inner
                block primary

        aside#sidebar-right.col-md-3
            .col-inner
                block sidebar
```

all.jade
    extends ./posts.jade

```
block title
    title All posts

block content
    .row
    section#forum-posts.col-md-9
        .col-inner
            block primary
                h1 All posts
                for post in posts
                    // list posts here...

      aside#sidebar-right.col-md-3
        .col-inner
            block sidebar
                h1 Hello from the Sidebar :)
```

single.jade

```
extends ./posts.jade

block title
    title Details for #{post.title}

block content
    .row
    section#forum-posts.col-md-9
        .col-inner
            // Single post data here...            

    aside#sidebar-right.col-md-3
        .col-inner
```

So, when I navigate to **/posts** it fetches the all.jade with no problem - everything works fine.

HERE IS THE ISSUE: when I go to **/posts/details/id** it fetches the single.jade template with all its dependencies (posts.jade, layout.jade), but it does not fetch the assets from the /public folder(css/style.css, bootstrap.min.css) files that I have pointed out in layout.jade, even though it extends it and the markup is shown on the page.

I'm not sure whether that's because of the Routing :(

Appreciate any ideas that you can share with me :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the contents of `/posts/details/id`?

Comment: Thanks for the response :) The route gets the content from the single.jade template that I've listed above. As you can see in my server.js file, I have set up an Express.Router() to operate within the /posts route, so when I do this -> postsRouter.get('/details/:id', **posts.details**); it actually goes to /posts/details/id and uses the details callback from my posts.js file:

Here is the posts.js(see the bold part in postsRouter.get() above):

    module.exports = {
 details: function(req, res) {
  res.render('single', {post: posts[req.params.id]});
 }
    }

Comment: Here is the more formatter code:
 `module.exports = {
 details: function(req, res) {
  res.render('single', {post: posts[req.params.id]});
 }
    }`

When I do this with the main /posts route it works just fine. May it be an issue with nesting routes ?